# Avoiding multiple lock attempts java

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, reentrantlock

I have the following method:

```
public foo bar(String id) {
    Lock localLock = lockUtil.lock(id);
    try {
        do something;
        return foo;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I need to override this method to take in another parameter.

```
public foo bar(String id, Integer index) {
    Lock localLock = lockUtil.lock(id);
    try {
        do something with index;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    return bar(id);
}
```

My question is, how can do achieve this without obtaining the locks twice (in case the second method is called)? I don't want to change the signature of the original method, since that would mean making changes at 10 different places in the system. I'd appreciate any ideas. I can give more clarification regarding the question, if required. Thanks.

Comment: Put the `return` statement inside the `try` and use a `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) is the documentation for ReerrantrantLock.

Comment: I thought of the ReentrantLock approach. But both the methods are using a different lock objects. I'm not sure it'll work for the given use case.

Comment: If they are different locks and you actually need both to be safe, then you will have to take both locks.

Comment: @merlin2011 Can you elaborate on that?